# How to transpose rows/columns without aggregation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know questions similar to this have been asked but I can't quite find what I'm looking for. I know about `PIVOT` but I don't think it does what I need.

I have survey data stored in a table that looks like this:

| Survey | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Blue |
| 1 | 2 | Puppy |
| 1 | 3 | Strawberry |
| 2 | 1 | Red |
| 2 | 2 | Kitten |
| 2 | 3 | Chocolate |

And I would like it transposed to this:

| Survey | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue | Puppy | Strawberry |
| 2 | Red | Kitten | Chocolate |

I know about the `PIVOT` function but that seems to require numeric data and aggregate functions. Is there a shortcut to do this? I know how to do it the long way, just wondering if there's a more efficient solution.

Using SQL Server 2016. Thanks!

Comment: You're correct that `pivot` requires aggregate functions but it can still work with non-numeric data. i.e.: `sum` requires numeric data, but `min` and `max` don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot doesn't actually require numeric data to work with aggregate functions, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.SurveyData (
  Survey int,
  Question int,
  Answer varchar(10)
);
insert dbo.SurveyData (Survey, Question, Answer)
values
  (1, 1, 'Blue'),
  (1, 2, 'Puppy'),
  (1, 3, 'Strawberry'),
  (2, 1, 'Red'),
  (2, 2, 'Kitten'),
  (2, 3, 'Chocolate');

select pvt.*
from (
  select Survey, 'Q'+cast(Question as varchar(10)) as Question, Answer
  from dbo.SurveyData
) Source
pivot (max(Answer) for Question in ( [Q1], [Q2], [Q3] )) pvt;
```

| Survey | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue | Puppy | Strawberry |
| 2 | Red | Kitten | Chocolate |

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation as well:

```
select survey,
       max(case when question = 1 then answer end) as q1,
       max(case when question = 2 then answer end) as q2,
       max(case when question = 3 then answer end) as q3
from t
group by survey;
```

The `max()` and `min()` aggregation functions work on (just about) all data types, including strings.

That said, you *could* do this without aggregation:

```
select t1.survey, t1.answer as q1, t2.answer as q2, t3.answer as q3
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.survey = t1.survey join
     t t3
     on t3.survey = t1.survey
where t1.question = 1 and t2.question = 2 and t3.question = 3;
```

I prefer the conditional aggregation approach because it is more versatile and less prone to error.